# How to reset formbuilder in another component?

Tags: angular, formbuilder

I am currently using angular material stepper to move between for steps. In step 1, I have a form registration, in step 2 I can submit and click on new registration which takes me back to step 1.
However the first registration details I entered are still in the form.

I have 2 components:

registration.component.ts

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  registrationForm: FormGroup;
   ...
}

export class SubmitComponent {

newRegistration(){
 // this.registrationForm.Reset();  ---> Logic needed here
}
}
```

Is it possible to reset the registrationForm that is in the registration component from the submit component?

Comment: try using service. or you can reset stepper and formGroup on submit.

Comment: Whats the structure? Are both components used in a parent component? I suggest to pass state with @Output event, so you can hear in the parent component on submit event in SubmitComponent and reset the FormGroup in RegistrationComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the comments on your question are valid resolutions here:

1. **Services** Services are meant to contain logic (and manage state in some situations), and multiple components can inject the same service instance. All steps/components in your wizard could communicate via this service.

`RegistrationComponent <-> RegistrationService <-> SubmitComponent`

```js
SubmitComponent.newRegistration() // calls RegistrationService.resetForm()

// maybe uses an EventEmitter here that the RegistrationComponent could subscribe to? 
// Or hold the form's value here, then tie the actual FormGroup to the value in the service? 
// Many different ways to handle this
RegistrationService.resetForm()  // emits something or updates form state/value

RegistrationComponent.registrationForm.reset() // calls the reset() method on the FormGroup
```

2. **Parent Component** If you have a parent template that wraps all wizard components, then `@Output()` is what you need:

```html
<wizard-wrapper>
  <registration-component #registration></registration-component>
  <submit-component (resetClicked)="registration.resetForm()"></submit-component>
</wizard-wrapper>
```

```js
class RegistrationComponent {

  resetForm() {
    this.registrationForm.reset();
  }
}


class SubmitComponent {

  @Output()
  public resetClicked = new EventEmitter();

  newRegistration() {
    // do stuff

    // on emission, the template detects this and calls the `resetForm` method in that component
    this.resetForm.emit();
  }
```